# how to disable the datepicker which is binding using knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am want to disable the input box and datepicker both based on an event in the following element:

```
<input data-bind="datepicker: billDate, enable: enableDate" id="endDate"/>
```

it actually disables and enables the input box but not the datepicker. 
How can I do it for both so the user cannot pick a date when the input box is disabled?

```
function setupDatePicker(resources, useChangeHandler){
    ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
            options.showOn = "button";
            options.buttonImage = resources.calendarGifUrl;
            options.buttonImageOnly = true;

            $(element).datepicker(options);


            if(useChangeHandler) {
                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "blur", function(){
                    if($(this).hasClass('input-error')){
                        showInput(this);
                    }
                });

                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    var enteredValue = $.trim(this.value);

                    $(this).removeClass("input-error");

                    var parsed = null;
                    var datepickerDateFullYear= null;
                    var datepickerDate = $(this).datepicker( "getDate" );

                    if (enteredValue){

                        var month = parseInt(enteredValue.split('/')[0]);
                        var day = parseInt(enteredValue.split('/')[1]);
                        var year = enteredValue.split('/')[2];

                        var validMonth = !isNaN(month) && month>=1 && month <=12;
                        var validDay = !isNaN(day) && day >= 1 && day <= 31;
                        var validYear = !(typeof year === 'undefined') && ($.trim(year).length==4);

                        if (validMonth && validDay && validYear) {

                            datepickerDateFullYear = datepickerDate.getFullYear();
                            enteredValue = month + "/" + day + "/" + datepickerDateFullYear;
                            parsed = Date.parse(enteredValue);
                        }
                    } else {
                        parsed = "";
                    }

                    if(parsed!=null) {

                        observable(enteredValue);
                        $(this).parent().parent().children(".field-error").remove();
                        enableSaveButtons();
                    } else {

                        observable(enteredValue);   //Force refresh
                        this.value = enteredValue;
                        $(this).addClass("input-error");
                        $(this).parent().parent().children(".field-error").remove();
                        $(this).parents("td").append("<span class='field-error invalid-date-error'>" + resources.invalid_date + "</span>");

                        disableSaveButtons();
                    }

                });
            }


            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                $(element).datepicker("destroy");
            });

        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What is the `datepicker` binding you are using?

Comment: Yes, but which specific binding to it are you using? IE where is the `datepicker` in `data-bind="datepicker...` defined?

Comment: I do not defined any datepicker. It is a binding feature provided by knockoutjs.

Comment: knockout doesn't have a default datepicker bindinghandler, it's got to be defined separately

Comment: if it's included in some other library/utility class you've pulled in, it's defined somewhere. search your project for `ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker`

Comment: you are right. I added the logic to my question.

Comment: when textbox disabled i see picker is not displayed check this http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/1552/ .

Comment: @supercool Thanks for making that.  I wonder if it's more [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/1553/) (click into the input within the first two seconds, it's then disabled with a timer - the date picker doesn't disable/close).  Nisman - can you confirm the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: I just can disable the input box not the datepicker. The user can pick a date yet.

Comment: if possible reproduce your scenario forking above fiddle or confirm is it something like james pointed out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple enable/disable on the input element as pointed out by @supercool should work but you can utilize the datepicker plugin's method to ensure that the datepicker is disabled by introducing a new binding like the code below

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enableDatepicker ={
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      if(!value){
        $(element).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(element).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
      }
      else{
          $(element).removeAttr("disabled");
          $(element).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
      }
  },
  update: function(element,valueAccessor){
      var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      if(!value){
        $(element).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(element).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
      }
      else{
          $(element).removeAttr("disabled");
          $(element).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
      }
  }
}
```

a forked version of @supercool's script is at http://jsfiddle.net/fwq8etpj/2/

then you html would look like

```
<input data-bind="datepicker: billDate, enableDatepicker: enableDate" id="endDate"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sam.C the only problem is that it does not make the datepicker icon disabled and still user can pick a date using the icon. What should I add to the binding handler so that it can disable the icon too?

Comment: You are right ... if you specify a button (datepicker icon) the plugin's disable function doesn't work. that is unfortunate and the plugin should have taken care of that. But you can hack a solution that would disable the  picker button ... I have updated the jsfiddle with a script that disables the button as well http://jsfiddle.net/fwq8etpj/4/.

Comment: Tried the code in this answer and found a couple of bugs in the code above. The code in the else statements should be $(element).datepicker( "option", "disabled", false );